# how to combine jquery 1 with latest

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, selectize.js, adminlte

i am using AdminLTE its using latest version of jquery its working perfect
but when i try and add selectize for tags its not working when i use jQuery v1.12.4 tags work perfectly but after that AdminLTE some drop menu not working what do i do now i stuck and too confuse

AdminLTE is using this JQuery

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

here is my selectize script

```
<script>
    $('#input-tags').selectize({
       delimiter: ',',
       persist: false,
       create: function(input) {
       return {
       value: input,
       text: input
           }
       }
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: what errors are thrown?

Comment: when i use JQuery v1.12 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (dashboard2.js:14)
    at j (jquery.js:3137)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3249)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3455)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:3496)